# scp only files not already in target directory

Tags: server, scp

I'm trying to copy a large number of files from my local machine down to my server using scp.  The problem I'm having is it takes a while and my internet occasionally drops.  So I would like to update the script below so that it only copies the files in the source "path1" on my local machine, that aren't already on my server at "path2".  Can anyone please suggest a slick way to do this?

```
scp -r /path1 username@servername:/path2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rsync` (`man rsync` for syntax). Very powerful tool for syncing files between local or remote locations. Parameters to note are `-n` or `--dry-run` to see what a command will do but without doing anything.

You can do all sorts of things like compare files on based on different things like file size or datetime as well as delete files for example so that if you delete files on the source they are also deleted on the destination.

Comment: thank you rsync worked great.  followed the syntax example from this post https://superuser.com/questions/1722338/rsync-from-macos-to-ubuntu "rsync -avzhe ssh ~/Folder ole@192.168.9.36:/home/ole/"